# how do i get column value from sql server 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

i have table where have 5 columns :

i wrote the code like this :

```
String SQLQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM aspnet_Users where Username=@uname AND Password = @pwd";
    using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Password);
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        boolReturnValue = (result > 0);
    }
```

here few more extra information i needed,if  above Username and password is correct, 
what i need is : **userid, and role** column data

Comment: I do hope you are using some form of hashing with your password storage and not just plain text (and using proper hashing not just a one time through a `sha256` that can be easily looked up in a rainbow table or other database), you don't say if you do are not, I just wanted to check that you are.

Answer (score 2):

Why you aren't doing that instead ?

```
string SQLQuery = "SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users where Username=@uname AND Password = @pwd";
[...]
object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == null)
{
    boolReturnValue = false;
}
else
{
    long userId = Convert.ToInt64(result);
    boolReturnValue = true;
}
```

Comment: and what if i need 2 values from table? let's say i need UserId and LastActiveDate

Comment: You need to use command.ExecuteReader() instead of command.ExecuteScalar()
ExecuteReader() will return a SqlDataReader and you need to iterate on it.


@Alireza : command.Parameters.AddWithValue isn't checking for SQL injection ?

Comment: @Falydoor Oops! You are right. I didn't notice the parameters are passed not being concatenated. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
String SQLQuery = "SELECT Top 1 UserId, role  FROM aspnet_Users where Username=@uname AND Password = @pwd";
    using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Password);

         SqlDataReader Reader = null;
         if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
                    sqlConnection.Open();
            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
           if (Reader.Read())
          {
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["UserId"]);
            string Role = Convert.ToString(Reader["role"]);

          }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the UserId instead of the Count(*) so your query should look like this :

```
SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users where Username=@uname AND Password = @pwd
```

Username should be unique so you shouldn't retrieve more than one row...you can add a Top 1 in case you have multiple same username with same password.

Comment: can you rewrite my code for perfect answer, please, i was checking username and password for login details and i need userid , if login successful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
SELECT count(*),userid,role FROM aspnet_Users where Username=@uname AND Password = @pwd Group by userid,role
```